# ChangeListener not giving correct old value

Tags: java, javafx-8

Here is the code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 29/07/15.
 */
public class ListPropertyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListProperty<String> lp =
                new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
        lp.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> c) {
                while(c.next()) {
                    String action = c.wasPermutated() ? "perm"
                            : c.wasUpdated() ? "upd"
                            : c.wasRemoved() ? "rem"
                            : c.wasAdded() ? "add" : "";
                    System.out.println("Action: " + action);
                    System.out.println("Removed: " + c.getRemoved());
                    System.out.println("Added: " + c.getAddedSubList());
                }
            }
        });

        lp.addListener(new ChangeListener<ObservableList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<String>> observable, ObservableList<String> oldValue, ObservableList<String> newValue) {
                System.out.println("List changed.");
                System.out.println("Old: " + oldValue);
                System.out.println("New: " + newValue);
            }
        });

        lp.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                System.out.println("List invalid");
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Add =========");
        lp.addAll("one", "two");
        System.out.println("Set =========");
        lp.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList("two", "three"));
        System.out.println("Remove ============");
        lp.remove("two");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Add =========
List invalid
List changed.
Old: [one, two]
New: [one, two]
Action: add
Removed: []
Added: [one, two]
Set =========
List invalid
List changed.
Old: [one, two]
New: [two, three]
Action: rem
Removed: [one, two]
Added: [two, three]
Remove ============
List invalid
List changed.
Old: [three]
New: [three]
Action: rem
Removed: [two]
Added: []
```

As you can see, the change listener behaved correctly only in the "Set" part.

Comment: well, while you don't state what you _do_ expect, you hit a deep pit, see my comment to @James_D [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31689191/203657) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of this is intended behavior.

A `ListProperty` is both an `ObjectProperty<ObservableList>` and an `ObservableList`.

Being an `ObjectProperty<ObservableList>` means it *wraps* (contains a reference to) an `ObservableList` and has `setValue(ObservableList)` (or `set(...)`) and `getValue()` methods. As an `ObjectProperty<ObservableList>`, you can register a `ChangeListener<ObservableList>` with it. If the *reference to the wrapped list* changes, by someone calling `setValue(ObservableList)`, the `ChangeListener<ObservableList>.changed(...)` method gets called on any registered `ChangeListener`, passing in a reference to the `ListProperty` itself, the old `ObservableList` reference, and the new `ObservableList` reference. You see this behavior when you call `set` in your code.

When you simply change the content of the list, however, the wrapped list is still the same physical object. So the "old list" and the "new list" are one and the same. It is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089169) that the change listener fires notifications in this case; hat-tip to @kleopatra for pointing this out.

A `ListProperty` also implements `ObservableList`, by delegating the `ObservableList` method calls to the wrapped list instance. This means if the content of the list change, any `ListChangeListener`s registered with the `ListProperty` get notified. Again, note in this case that there is only one list object; it's just that its contents have been modified.

You can get details about changes that occur to an `ObservableList` via the `Change` object passed to the `onChanged(...)` method, as you observe in the output from your `onChanged` method. Note that `c.getFrom()` and `c.getTo()` will give you the indexes of the items that have changed as well.

I almost never have a need for a `ListProperty`: in the vast majority of use cases it is enough for me to just use a plain `ObservableList` implementation. Controls that are based on lists of objects (such as `ListView` and `TableView`) use them, so you can call `setItems(...)` to pass in an existing `ObservableList` if you need, or (probably more usually) you can just call `getItems()` to retrieve the current list and modify it. As you can see from the explanation above, the `ListProperty` allows these controls to observe either kind of change. But it is likely that in your own code, you will use `ObservableList` directly far more often than you use a `ListProperty`.

Comment: a) it's a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095404) that the ChangeListener fires on modifications to the underlying list b) using a ListProperty (vs. a simple list-valued ObservableProperty) is the [only option](https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/wiki/List-Valued-Property-Woes) (apart from registering an InvalidationListener) to reliably get notified on identity changes of the list (this was the root cause for a whole bunch of bugs around selectionModels, f.i. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089169 )

Comment: For a),  I was wondering a while after I wrote that why notifications were getting fired. I will update the answer: thanks for that. For b), yes, that's correct, but in client code it's rarely necessary to allow identity changes to the list (in my experience, anyway: ymmv)

Comment: yes, mileage for b) certainly varies - but developers should be aware of the caveat :-)

Comment: @kleopatra They did file a patch: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/rev/56c82bf7257e Did that work out for you?

Comment: @qed yes, it did indeed solve the selectionModel related issues, as noted in the patch header. BTW, just noticed that I mixed up the bug references in my first comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095404 is about selectionModel issues, https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089169 is about ListProperty firing on modification of the underlying list. Sorry for causing confusion.